# Retrieve URL from tcm

Tags: xslt, webforms, tridion

I'm trying to retrieve the URL of a Multimedia Component in render xslt but it still fails.

I can pick up the tcm URI. Is there any way to get the URL from that?

I tried with tcmse:PublishBinary function but it fails with the error "Namespace 'http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.1/TcmScriptAssistant' does not contain any functions."

```
<table cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px" style="border: 0; padding: 0px; width: 100%"> 
    <xsl:for-each select="twf:items/twf:item">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <!-- <xsl:value-of select="twf:webformscomponentlink/@xlink:href" /> -->
                <!-- <xsl:value-of select="tcmse:PublishBinary(string(twf:webformscomponentlink/@xlink:href))" /> -->
                <span>
                    <xsl:call-template name="replace-new-lines">
                        <xsl:with-param name="string">
                            <xsl:value-of select="twf:linklabel" />
                        </xsl:with-param>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                </span>
                <xsl:element name="a">
                    <xsl:attribute name="href">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="twf:webformscomponentlink/@xlink:href">
                                <xsl:value-of select="twf:webformscomponentlink/@xlink:href" /> 
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>#</xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="twf:linktext" />
                </xsl:element>    
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

Thank you very much

Comment: You don't explain what you're trying to do. The TcmScriptAssistent is available by default if you are doing a "legacy" style XSLT component template in Tridion. Is this what you're doing?

Comment: Did you have the namespace for tcmse declared. `xmlns:tcmse="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.1/TcmScriptAssistant"`. Seems like you are using with in WebForms templates, so this probably legacy style.

Comment: Is this legacy XSLT templates or XSLT TBBs using the XSLT Mediator? What version of Tridion are you using?

Comment: Could even be that the TcmScriptAssistant isn't properly installed? Apparently the namespace declaration for the TcmScriptAssistent is there but if the extension object isn't...

Answer (score 1):

You are mentioning you are trying to resolve a Multimedia Component in the Render XSLT, and in your tags I see WebForms, so I'm assuming its the Render XSLT of a SDL Tridion WebForms Component template.

A WebForm is a Dynamic Component Presentation, and it's Component Template uses two XSLT's, one in the Source tab (the Expand XSLT), which is executed at Publish time, when the Publisher renders the Template code on the CMS. The Dynamic Template is the other, it contains an XSLT, which at Publishing time is copied as is to the Content Broker.  At request time of your WebForms Component Presentation, the Dynamic Template is used to transform the Expand XML into your WebForm.

So because the Dynamic Template is executed on request time, at that point the TcmScriptAssistant isn't available anymore (it only exists on the Content Manager side at Publishing time). The solution is to resolve the Multimedia Component in the Expand Template, using `tcmse:PublishBinary()`, in the Render Template you can only transform/display the outcome of the Expand Template, but you don;t have access to the CM functions at that point.